# data.map function stops working after second call

Tags: javascript

I have a script which is calling for API and receiving the data every hour and automatically stores it in database.
The script by itself works without any problem on first call, but when there is time for script to be called second time it gives me an error.

Example: I start the script at 13:30, at 14:00 the script start receiving the data and stores it in MongoDB. For the first time is working good, but when the another time comes (at 15:00) the script doesn't want to start and I receive this error - `TypeError: data.map is not a function`

My guess that the problem is with `setTimeout` function cause before I add it, everything was working perfect. The thing is that I need to have a 2 second delay, otherwise I will receive an IP ban from API.

**Full code example:**

```
var requestPromise = require('request-promise');
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const schedule = require('node-schedule');
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

var symbols = ["ZRXBTC",
    "LENDBTC",
    "AEBTC",
    "AIONBTC",
    "ALGOBTC",
    "ARDRBTC",

];
let cnt = 0;
const callIt = () => {
    fetch(`https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=${symbols[cnt]}&interval=30m&limit=1`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            const btcusdtdata = data.map(d => {
                return {
                    Open: parseFloat(d[1]),
                    High: parseFloat(d[2]),
                    Low: parseFloat(d[3]),
                    Close: parseFloat(d[4]),
                    Volume: parseFloat(d[5]),
                    Timespan: 30,
                }
            });
            console.log(btcusdtdata);
            saveToDatebase(btcusdtdata);
            cnt++;
            if (cnt < symbols.length) setTimeout(callIt, 3000);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        })
};

const j = schedule.scheduleJob('*/0 * * * *', callIt)

const saveToDatebase = function(BTCdata) {

    const url = 'mongodb+srv://username:password3@cluster0-1kunr.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

    var today = new Date();
    var date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
    var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
    var dateTime = date + ' ' + time;

    MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, db) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        const dbo = db.db('CryptoCurrencies');
        const myobj = { Name: symbols[cnt - 1], Array: BTCdata, Date: dateTime };
        dbo.collection(`${symbols[cnt - 1]}`).insertOne(myobj, (error, res) => {
            if (error) throw error;
            console.log('1 document inserted');
            db.close();
        });
    });

};
```

Shortly: This script receives data every hour and stores it in MongoDB. I need to use setTimeout  to call properties from array with a delay, otherwise I will receive IP ban from API. The script is fine when it's working first time, but when it's time for a second call it give's me an error - `TypeError: data.map is not a function`.

This problem appears only after I add `setTimeout()` function.

Comment: By the way, it seems a bit useless that you are requiring three libraries that all handle HTTP requests. One should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the `cnt` variable is not reset to `0`, returning `undefined` in the url on the second run (`symbols[symbols.length] === undefined`), returning a `404` from the fetch call, having no json body and thus dereferencing `map` on a non-array object.

**Edit:**
The simple solution is to reset the counter to 0 once it has reached the end of the array.

```js
const callIt = () => {
    fetch(`https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=${symbols[cnt]}&interval=30m&limit=1`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            const btcusdtdata = data.map(d => {
                return {
                    Open: parseFloat(d[1]),
                    High: parseFloat(d[2]),
                    Low: parseFloat(d[3]),
                    Close: parseFloat(d[4]),
                    Volume: parseFloat(d[5]),
                    Timespan: 30,
                }
            });
            console.log(btcusdtdata);
            saveToDatebase(btcusdtdata);
            cnt++;
            if (cnt < symbols.length) {
                setTimeout(callIt, 3000);
            } else {
                cnt = 0; // reset counter to 0 when cnt >= symbols.length to "prepare" for the next iteration initiated by schedule.scheduleJob
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As Shikkie already pointed out, the issue is that `cnt` is never reset to zero.

However, the whole way it currently works is a bit roundabout anyway, it can be cleaned up by using an async function, thereby also eliminating the problem:

```js
// This gives us an async function "delay" that waits for the given amount of time
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

// This is the new definition of callIt - no cnt variable declared outside anymore
const callIt = async () => {
  for (const symbol of symbols) {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(`https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=${symbol}&interval=30m&limit=1`)
      const data = await res.json()

      const ticker = data.map(d => ({
        Open: parseFloat(d[1]),
        High: parseFloat(d[2]),
        Low: parseFloat(d[3]),
        Close: parseFloat(d[4]),
        Volume: parseFloat(d[5]),
        Timespan: 30
      }))
      console.log(`Received ticker for ${symbol}:`, ticker)

      // This sounds like it's asynchronous as well, so maybe you want to
      // check out how errors are handled inside of this function to avoid
      // crashing the whole process due to an async error. You could return
      // a promise from the function as well and then just `await` it here.
      // Also, I don't see how you differentiate here between the individual
      // market pairs... Maybe you want to pass the variable `symbol` too.
      saveToDatebase(ticker)

      // Wait 3 seconds before doing the next request
      await delay(3000)
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(`An error occured while processing ${symbol}:`, err)
    }
  }
}
```

(Note: The `delay` function could also have been generated using `require('util').promisify(setTimeout)`, however the way I wrote now is more platform-independent and doesn't rely on node.js as environment.)